# How to use the JavaScript += with a switch statement

Tags: javascript, syntax, switch-statement

I have the following:

```
let buttonClass = '';
buttonClass += link ? ' button-link ' : '';
```

I would like to add:

```
let buttonClass = '';
buttonClass += link ? ' button-link ' : '';
buttonClass += 
  (return switch(textAlign) {
        case "right":
          "ta-r"
          break;
        case "left":
          "ta-l"
          break;
        default:
          "ta-c"
})
```

The above is erring... How can I use `+=` with a switch statement as seen above?

Comment: `switch` is not an expression. It cannot be used 'in place' of a value. One option is to use a function (inline/IIFE or not) with a switch-return in it..

Comment: thanks user.. can you provide an example so I can mark the answer? thanks

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to do that.

An alternative is using **[IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)**

```js
var textAlign = 'right';
var buttonClass = "class-name-"
buttonClass += (function() {
  switch (textAlign) {
    case "right":
      return "ta-r"
    case "left":
      return "ta-l"
    default:
      return "ta-c"
  }
})();

console.log(buttonClass);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an object:

```
buttonClass += {
  "right": "ta-r",
  "left": "ta-l",
}[textAlign] || "ta-c";
```

That instantiates a throw-away object (which you could of course replace with a more permanent object) and looks up the current `textAlign` value. If no entry is found, the `[ ]` expression will return `undefined` so the `||` provides the default.

Comment: love the simplicity here... but I need to build `buttonClass += `

Comment: @AnApprentice what's wrong with the `buttonClass` assignment you've already got?

Comment: @AnApprentice ah, you edited your question and changed it significantly. Please try not to do that.

Comment: @AnApprentice the only difference is that `buttonClass` appears on the left-hand side of `+=` instead of `textAlign`.

Comment: this great. will accept as soon as SO lets me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

By itself, **[`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)** does not return a value that you can insert into a larger expression. It branches into one set of code that is executed. A simple way to make this work is to set the value of a variable via the `switch`:

```
let buttonClass = '';
buttonClass += link ? ' button-link ' : '';
var result = null; // Answer will wind up here
switch(textAlign) {
        case "right":
          result = "ta-r";
          break;
        case "left":
          result = "ta-l";
          break;
        default:
          result = "ta-c";
}

// Whatever the switch set the result to, use it here:
textAlign += result;
```

As others have pointed out as well, you can certainly wrap `switch` with a `function` and have the function return a value based on the outcome of the `switch`.

```
function wrapSwitch(tAlign){
  switch(tAlign){
        case "right":
          return "ta-r";
        case "left":
          return "ta-l";
        default:
          return "ta-c";
  }
}

textAlign += wrapSwitch(textAlign);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let buttonClass = '';
buttonClass += link ? ' button-link ' : '';

const switchFn = (textAlign) => {
    switch(textAlign) {
        case "right":
            return "ta-r";

        case "left":
            return "ta-l";

        default:
            return "ta-c";
    }
}

textAlign += switchFn(textAlign)
```

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow should include an explanation of the problem and solution. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)